# Plugin AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id issue

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter

My App is perfectly running in Android Emulator but when i run my app in IOS emulator, red screen shows up with this message. And in the terminal it showing [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok Finally got the Problem actually. The errors were actually warnings and didnot affected my IOS build. There was a caching problem in the main.dart file. Al thought i still didnot find how to remove the warnings.